# There is a given polynomial: $p(x)=(x^n-x+1)^{2018}(3x^{n+3}+2x-4)^{11}$

Tags: polynomials

$$p(x)=(x^n-x+1)^{2018}(3x^{n+3}+2x-4)^{11}$$

1. What is the remainder if you divide this polynomial with $g(x)=x-1$
2. What should $n$ be that the degree of the polynomial is $4091$
3. Calculate the sum of all the coefficients of polynomial $p(x)$

Comment: What have you done on this problem?  Also, is this a problem in an ongoing contest?  ("Current year" problems often come from contests.)

Comment: This is not a problem from a contest. I don't know how to solve this problems.

Comment: "power of polynomial" = "degree of polynomial"?

Comment: Yes sorry, degrees

Comment: You really need to try this yourself. For a hint: I got all the answers just by looking at the question - limited computation required.

Comment: I still don't have a clue

Comment: @MarkBennet Well for b), I could only solve "is *approximately* $4091$" without computation and hope that the answer is exact :)

Comment: Try $p(x)=(x-1)q(x)+r$ with $r$ a constant remainder.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen There is only one viable solution and it isn't so difficult to check that it works. I didn't say without computation, but "limited computation".

Comment: How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a)for finding remainder when divided by $x-1$

use remainder theorem plug $x=1$

$p(1)=1$ so $1$ will be remainder

(b) put $n=2$ you'll get polynomial of degree $(2\times 2018)+(5\times11)=4091$

(c) sum of all coefficients will be also $p(1)$ which is $= 1$